# How can I restrict access to an App Maker application?

Tags: google-app-maker

I want to make an App Maker application that contains sensitive data. How do I make it so only certain users or groups can access the application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application is automatically restricted to members of your domain, but if you’d like to further restrict usage you can edit the settings of a particular deployment of your application to restrict usage. Under “Application access” click “Only allow access to specific users”, then you can add any combination of users and Google groups. Note you can only add users and groups within your domain.

There are also lots of other security issues you might want to consider. Review https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/overview for more details.